# I am having issues with implementing swap fees on transfer for DEX

Tags: ink, rust, decentralised

Below is my lib.rs file for the token contract and it uses the Cardinal Cryptography PSP22 sample at https://github.com/Cardinal-Cryptography/PSP22

I am trying to implement swap for the transfer taxes to native tokens, to no avail!

```
#![cfg_attr(not(feature = "std"), no_std, no_main)]

#[cfg(feature = "contract")]
#[ink::contract]
mod token {
    use psp22::{PSP22Data, PSP22Error, PSP22Event, PSP22Metadata, PSP22};
    use psp22::PSP22Error::Custom;
    use ink::prelude::{string::String, vec::Vec};

    use ink::{
        env::{
            call::{build_call, ExecutionInput, Selector},
            DefaultEnvironment
        }
    };

    #[ink(storage)]
    pub struct Token {
        data: PSP22Data,
        name: Option<String>,
        symbol: Option<String>,
        decimals: u8,
        owner: Option<AccountId>,
        reentrancy_lock: bool,
        trading: bool,
        pool_address: Option<AccountId>
    }

    impl Token {
        #[ink(constructor)]
        pub fn new(
            name: Option<String>,
            symbol: Option<String>,
            decimals: u8,
            total_supply: Balance
        ) -> Self {
            let owner = Self::env().caller();
            Self {
                data: PSP22Data::new(total_supply, owner),
                name,
                symbol,
                decimals,
                owner: Some(owner),
                reentrancy_lock: false,
                trading: false,
                pool_address: None
            }
        }

        fn emit_events(&self, events: Vec<PSP22Event>) {
            for event in events {
                match event {
                    PSP22Event::Transfer { from, to, value } => {
                        self.env().emit_event(Transfer { from, to, value })
                    }
                    PSP22Event::Approval {
                        owner,
                        spender,
                        amount,
                    } => self.env().emit_event(Approval {
                        owner,
                        spender,
                        amount,
                    }),
                }
            }
        }

        #[ink(message)]
        pub fn enable_trading(&mut self, pool_address: AccountId) -> Result<(), PSP22Error> {
            if self.env().caller() != self.owner.unwrap() {
                return Err(Custom(String::from("OnlyOwnerAllowed")));
            }
            self.pool_address = Some(pool_address);
            self.trading = true;
            Ok(())
        }

        #[inline]
        pub fn distribute_fees(&mut self) -> Result<(), PSP22Error> {

            let _ = ink::env::CallFlags::default().set_allow_reentry(true);

            if self.reentrancy_lock == true {
                return Ok(()); // Do not act if there is a reentry
            }

            self.reentrancy_lock = true;

            let amount = self.data.balance_of(self.env().account_id());
            
            if amount > 0 {
                self.swap_for_azero(amount)?;
            }

            self.reentrancy_lock = false;

            Ok(())

        }

        #[inline]
        pub fn swap_for_azero(&mut self, amount: Balance) -> Result<(), PSP22Error> {

            let pool_address = self.pool_address.unwrap();

            let azero_out = build_call::<DefaultEnvironment>()
            .call(pool_address)
            .exec_input(ExecutionInput::new(Selector::new(ink::selector_bytes!(
                "get_a0_amount_out_without_deduction"
            ))).push_arg(amount))
            .returns::<Balance>()
            .try_invoke().unwrap().unwrap();

            self.data.approve(self.env().account_id(), pool_address, amount)?;

            if build_call::<DefaultEnvironment>()
            .call(pool_address)
            .exec_input(ExecutionInput::new(Selector::new(ink::selector_bytes!(
                "swap_psp22"
            )))
            
            .push_arg(amount)
            .push_arg(azero_out)
            .push_arg(100 * 10u128.pow(12)))

            .returns::<()>()
            .try_invoke().is_err() {
                return Err(Custom(String::from("PSP22 Swap Failed")));
            }

            Ok(())

        }

    }

    #[ink(event)]
    pub struct Approval {
        #[ink(topic)]
        owner: AccountId,
        #[ink(topic)]
        spender: AccountId,
        amount: u128,
    }

    #[ink(event)]
    pub struct Transfer {
        #[ink(topic)]
        from: Option<AccountId>,
        #[ink(topic)]
        to: Option<AccountId>,
        value: u128,
    }

    impl PSP22 for Token {
        #[ink(message)]
        fn total_supply(&self) -> u128 {
            self.data.total_supply()
        }

        #[ink(message)]
        fn balance_of(&self, owner: AccountId) -> u128 {
            self.data.balance_of(owner)
        }

        #[ink(message)]
        fn allowance(&self, owner: AccountId, spender: AccountId) -> u128 {
            self.data.allowance(owner, spender)
        }

        #[ink(message)]
        fn transfer(
            &mut self,
            to: AccountId,
            value: u128,
            _data: Vec<u8>,
        ) -> Result<(), PSP22Error> {
            if self.env().caller() == self.env().account_id() || self.trading == false {
                let events = self.data.transfer(self.env().caller(), to, value)?;
                self.emit_events(events);
            }
            else {
                let fee = (value * 3) / 100;
                let amt = value - fee;

                let _ = self.data.transfer(self.env().caller(), self.env().account_id(), fee)?;

                if self.env().caller() != self.pool_address.unwrap() {
                    self.distribute_fees()?;
                }

                let events = self.data.transfer(self.env().caller(), to, amt)?;
                self.emit_events(events);
            }
            Ok(())
        }

        #[ink(message)]
        fn transfer_from(
            &mut self,
            from: AccountId,
            to: AccountId,
            value: u128,
            _data: Vec<u8>,
        ) -> Result<(), PSP22Error> {

            if from == self.env().account_id() || self.trading == false {
                let events = self
                .data
                .transfer_from(self.env().caller(), from, to, value)?;
                self.emit_events(events);
            }
            else {
                let fee = (value * 3) / 100;
                let amt = value - fee;

                let _ = self
                .data
                .transfer_from(self.env().caller(), from, self.env().account_id(), fee)?;

                if from != self.pool_address.unwrap() {
                    self.distribute_fees()?;
                }

                let events = self
                .data
                .transfer_from(self.env().caller(), from, to, amt)?;
                self.emit_events(events);
            }


            let events = self
                .data
                .transfer_from(self.env().caller(), from, to, value)?;
            self.emit_events(events);
            Ok(())
        }

        #[ink(message)]
        fn approve(&mut self, spender: AccountId, value: u128) -> Result<(), PSP22Error> {
            let events = self.data.approve(self.env().caller(), spender, value)?;
            self.emit_events(events);
            Ok(())
        }

        #[ink(message)]
        fn increase_allowance(
            &mut self,
            spender: AccountId,
            delta_value: u128,
        ) -> Result<(), PSP22Error> {
            let events = self
                .data
                .increase_allowance(self.env().caller(), spender, delta_value)?;
            self.emit_events(events);
            Ok(())
        }

        #[ink(message)]
        fn decrease_allowance(
            &mut self,
            spender: AccountId,
            delta_value: u128,
        ) -> Result<(), PSP22Error> {
            let events = self
                .data
                .decrease_allowance(self.env().caller(), spender, delta_value)?;
            self.emit_events(events);
            Ok(())
        }
    }

    impl PSP22Metadata for Token {
        #[ink(message)]
        fn token_name(&self) -> Option<String> {
            self.name.clone()
        }
        #[ink(message)]
        fn token_symbol(&self) -> Option<String> {
            self.symbol.clone()
        }
        #[ink(message)]
        fn token_decimals(&self) -> u8 {
            self.decimals
        }
    }
    
}
```

When I enable trading, the contract gets trapped in the transfer_from and transfer methods respectively.

How do I fix the problem? Can anyone spot out the issue? Is there something wrong somewhere?

You can use `cargo +nightly contract build --release --features "contract" to build (compile) the code.

Also, below is the Cargo.toml file content:

```
[package]
name = "psp22"
version = "0.2.1"
edition = "2021"
authors = ["Edinyanga Ottoho"]

[dependencies]
ink = { version = "4.3", default-features = false }

scale = { package = "parity-scale-codec", version = "3", default-features = false, features = ["derive"] }
scale-info = { version = "2.9", default-features = false, features = ["derive"], optional = true }

psp22 = { git = "https://github.com/Cardinal-Cryptography/PSP22.git", default-features = false }

[lib]
path = "lib.rs"

[features]
contract = []
default = ["std"]
std = [
    "ink/std",
    "scale/std",
    "scale-info/std",
    "psp22/std"
]

ink-as-dependency = []
```